# Ideas about Generating Untraceable Invoice IDs

Tags: c#, sql, data-structures, numbers, integer

I want to print invoices for customers in my app. Each invoice has an **Invoice ID**. I want IDs to be:

- Sequential (ids entered lately come late)
- 32 bit integers
- **Not easily** traceable like 1 2 3 so that people can't tell how many items we sell.

**An idea of my own:**
 Number of **seconds** since a specific date & time (e.g. 1/1/2010 00 AM).

Any other ideas how to generate these numbers ?

Comment: Are you sure to be allowed to do this by your local laws?

Comment: Do the 'numbers' have to be strictly numeric?  Or can they contain alpha characters also?

Comment: @GarryVass they should be **strictly numeric** and **strictly 32 bit integer** !

Comment: @Steve Yes, but if you know anything more, I'm very eager to hear it

Comment: The other question that arises in cases like these is: does the generator have to be strictly thread safe?

Comment: @GarryVass very good question. Yes it should be thread safe, but it could be done by catching exception. For example in my idea I will add my new record, if I encountered the duplicate record exception I will run a `Sleep(1000)` and then try again. In my app there aren't many users. There are less than 10 and the work load is very low. So this strategy is feasible. How ever, if there is any other way to do this more readily, I'll be happy to know it. I don't want to use `Guid` because its 128 bit, I don't want my invoice id take that much!

Comment: Last questions: must the generated numbers be reversible? i.e., do you need to take a given number and reverse out its 'true' sequence number?  Or just its relative sequential position?  And also do you have a plan for unit testing?

Comment: @GarryVass you're good at asking questions :). No just relative sequential position suffice. Tell me more about "unit testing" ?!

Comment: To achieve full confidence that your 'Id Service' avoids collisions and behavioural anomalies, it would be developed in an isolated state and examined with unit tests (MsTest or NUnit or what-ever).  But that's only if you are a TDD guy.

Comment: @GarryVass If he's a "TDD guy" he will develop the unit tests bevor developing the "ID service". No matter what guy he is - an "ID Service" *should be unit tested* nonetheless!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't like the idea of using time. You can run into all sorts of issues - time differences, several events happening in a single second and so on.

If you want something sequential and not easily traceable, how about generating a random number between 1 and whatever you wish (for example 100) for each new Id. Each new Id will be the previous Id + the random number.

You can also add a constant to your IDs to make them look more impressive. For example you can add 44323 to all your IDs and turn IDs 15, 23 and 27 into 44338, 44346 and 44350.

Answer (score 8):

There are two problems in your question. One is solvable, one isn't (with the constraints you give).

### Solvable: Unguessable numbers

The first one is quite simple: It should be hard for a customer to guess a valid invoice number (or the next valid invoice number), when the customer has access to a set of valid invoice numbers.

You can solve this with your constraint:

Split your invoice number in two parts:

1. A 20 bit prefix, taken from a sequence of increasing numbers (e.g. the natural numbers 0,1,2,...)
2. A 10 bit suffix that is randomly generated

With these scheme, there are a bout 1 million valid invoice numbers. You can precalculate them and store them in the database. When presented with a invoice number, check if it is in your database. When it isn't, it's not valid.

Use a SQL sequence for handing out numbers. When issuing a new (i.e. unused) invoice number, increment the seuqnce and issue the n-th number from the precalculated list (order by value).

### Not solvable: Guessing the number of customers

When you want to prevent a customer having a number of valid invoice numbers from guessing how much invoice numbers you have issued yet (and there for how much customers you have): This is not possible.

You have hare a variant form the so called "[German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)". I nthe second world war, the allies used serial numbers printed on the gear box of german tanks to guestimate, how much tanks Germany had produced. This worked, because the serial number was increasing without gaps.

But even when you increase the numbers with gaps, the solution for the German tank problem still works. It is quite easy:

1. You use the method described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) to guess the highest issued invoice number
2. You guess the mean difference between two successive invoice numbers and divide the number through this value
3. You can use linear regression to get a stable delta value (if it exists).

Now you have a good guess about the order of magnitude of the number of invoices (200, 15000, half an million, etc.).

This works as long there (theoretically) exists a mean value for two successive invoice numbers. This is usually the case, even when using a random number generator, because most random number generators are designed to have such a mean value.

There is a counter measure: You have to make sure that there exists no mean value for the gap of two successive numbers. A random number generator with this property can be constructed very easy.

Example:

1. Start with the last invoice number plus one as current number
2. Multiply the current number with a random number >=2. This is your new current number.
3. Get a random bit: If the bit is 0, the result is your current number. Otherwise go back to step 2.

While this will work in theory, you will very soon run out of 32 bit integer numbers.

I don't think there is a practical solution for this problem. Either the gap between two successive number has a mean value (with little variance) and you can guess the amount of issued numbers easily. Or you will run out of 32 bit numbers very quickly.

### Snakeoil (non working solutions)

Don't use any time based solution. The timestamp is usually easy guessable (probably an approximately correct timestamp will be printed somewhere on invoice). Using timestamps usually makes it easier for the attacker, not harder.

Don't use insecure random numbers. Most random number generators are not cryptographically safe. They usually have mathematical properties that are good for statistics but bad for your security (e.g. a predicable distribution, a stable mean value, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete explanation. You told me things that opened my vision about this issue, especially for future larger jobs.

Comment: If the timestamp is detailed enough, and invoices are created randomly during the day, how can a customer deduce anything but the frequency of his own invoices? He won't have access to successive timestamps.

Comment: The problem is, timestamps are not random. The most significant bits are easily guessable. The leas significant bits are random in theroy but not in practice. The real resolution of your timestamp is usually very limited (milliseconds at best, might be only seconds). And various timer based actions (buffering, multi tasking, sleeping until the next full second, ) and regularities in your algorithms influence the distribution of the least significant bits in a way that makes them also guessable. So timestamps are practically not as random as they may appear on the first sight.

Comment: To be untraceable, the timestamps need not be very precise and the timestamp may be utterly predictable. As long as one timestamp doesn't hint at how many more timestamps were handed out today.

Answer (score 5):

One solution may involve Exclusive OR (XOR) binary bitmaps. The result function is **reversible**, **may generate non-sequential numbers** (if the first bit of the least significant byte is set to 1), and is extremely easy to implement. And, as long as you use a reliable sequence generator (your database, for example,) there is no need for thread safety concerns.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx), 'the result [of a exclusive-OR operation] is true if and only if exactly one of its operands is true.' reverse logic says that equal operands will always result false.

As an example, I just generated a 32-bit sequence on Random.org. This is it:

```
11010101111000100101101100111101
```

This binary number translates to **3588381501** in decimal, **0xD5E25B3D** in hex. Let's call it your *base key*.

Now, lets generate some values using the *([base key] XOR [ID])* formula. In C#, that's what your encryption function would look like:

```
    public static long FlipMask(long baseKey, long ID)
    {
        return baseKey ^ ID;
    }
```

The following list contains some generated content. Its columns are as follows:

- ID
- Binary representation of ID
- Binary value after XOR operation
- Final, 'encrypted' decimal value

  ```
  0 | 000 | 11010101111000100101101100111101 | 3588381501
  1 | 001 | 11010101111000100101101100111100 | 3588381500
  2 | 010 | 11010101111000100101101100111111 | 3588381503
  3 | 011 | 11010101111000100101101100111110 | 3588381502
  4 | 100 | 11010101111000100101101100111001 | 3588381497
  ```

In order to reverse the generated key and determine the original value, you only need to do the same XOR operation using the same base key. Let's say we want to obtain the original value of the second row:

```
    11010101111000100101101100111101 XOR
    11010101111000100101101100111100 =
    00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Which was indeed your original value.

Now, [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1885392/stefan-schwetschke) made very good points, and the first topic is crucial.

In order to cover his concerns, you may reserve the last, say, 8 bytes to be purely random garbage (which I believe is called a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)), which you generate when encrypting the original ID and ignore when reversing it. That would heavily increase your security at the expense of a generous slice of all the possible positive integer numbers with 32 bits (16,777,216 instead of 4,294,967,296, or 1/256 of it.)

A class to do that would look like this:

```
public static class int32crypto
{
    // C# follows ECMA 334v4, so Integer Literals have only two possible forms -
    // decimal and hexadecimal.
    // Original key:               0b11010101111000100101101100111101
    public static long baseKey = 0xD5E25B3D;

    public static long encrypt(long value)
    {
        // First we will extract from our baseKey the bits we'll actually use.
        // We do this with an AND mask, indicating the bits to extract.
        // Remember, we'll ignore the first 8. So the mask must look like this:
        // Significance mask:      0b00000000111111111111111111111111
        long _sigMask = 0x00FFFFFF;

        // sigKey is our baseKey with only the indicated bits still true.
        long _sigKey = _sigMask & baseKey;

        // nonce generation. First security issue, since Random()
        // is time-based on its first iteration. But that's OK for the sake
        // of explanation, and safe for most circunstances.
        // The bits it will occupy are the first eight, like this:
        // OriginalNonce:          0b000000000000000000000000NNNNNNNN
        long _tempNonce = new Random().Next(255);

        // We now shift them to the last byte, like this:
        // finalNonce:             0bNNNNNNNN000000000000000000000000
        _tempNonce = _tempNonce << 0x18;

        // And now we mix both Nonce and sigKey, 'poisoning' the original
        // key, like this:

        long _finalKey = _tempNonce | _sigKey;

        // Phew! Now we apply the final key to the value, and return
        // the encrypted value.

        return _finalKey ^ value;


    }

    public static long decrypt(long value)
    {
        // This is easier than encrypting. We will just ignore the bits
        // we know are used by our nonce.
        long _sigMask = 0x00FFFFFF;
        long _sigKey = _sigMask & baseKey;

        // We will do the same to the informed value:
        long _trueValue = _sigMask & value;

        // Now we decode and return the value:
        return _sigKey ^ _trueValue;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

perhaps idea may come from the millitary? group invoices in blocks like these:
28th Infantry Division
--1st Brigade
---1st BN
----A Co
----B Co
---2nd BN
----A Co
----B Co
--2nd Brigade
---1st BN
----A Co
----B Co
---2nd BN
----A Co
----B Co
--3rd Brigade
---1st BN
----A Co
----B Co
---2nd BN
----A Co
----B Co
http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=432978
groups don't have to be sequential but numbers in groups do

**UPDATE**

Think about above as groups differentiated by place, time, person, etc. For example: create group using seller temporary ID, changing it every 10 days or by office/shop.

There is another idea, you may say a bit weird but... when I think of it I like it more and more. Why not to count down these invoices? **Choose a big number and count down**. It's easy to trace number of items when counting up, but counting down? How anyone would guess where is a starting point? It's easy to implement,
 too.

Comment: Nice, but the problem is that my items are all of the same category, anyway thanks for the new idea

Answer (score 2):

If the orders sit in an inbox until a single person processes them each morning, seeing that it took that person till 16:00 before he got round to creating my invoice will give me the impression that he's been busy. Getting the 9:01 invoice makes me feel like I'm the only customer today.

But if you generate the ID at the time when I place my order, the timestamp tells me nothing.

I think I therefore actually like the timestamps, assuming that collisions where two customers simultaneously need an ID created are rare.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the code below that I use newsequentialid() to generate a sequential number then convert that to a [bigint]. As that generates a consistent increment of 4294967296 I simply divide that number by the [id] on the table (it could be rand() seeded with nanoseconds or something similar). The result is a number that is always less than 4294967296 so I can safely add it and be sure I'm not overlapping the range of the next number.

Peace
Katherine

```
declare @generator as table ( 
[id] [bigint], 
[guid] [uniqueidentifier] default( newsequentialid()) not null, 
[converted] as (convert([bigint], convert ([varbinary](8), [guid], 1))) + 10000000000000000000,
[converted_with_randomizer] as (convert([bigint], convert ([varbinary](8), [guid], 1))) + 10000000000000000000 + cast((4294967296 / [id]) as [bigint])
);

insert into @generator ([id])
values      (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);

select [id],
   [guid],
   [converted],
   [converted] - lag([converted],
                     1.0)
                     over (
                         order by [id])                 as [orderly_increment],
   [converted_with_randomizer],
   [converted_with_randomizer] - lag([converted_with_randomizer],
                                     1.0)
                                     over (
                                         order by [id]) as [disorderly_increment]
from   @generator
order  by [converted];
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reasons for the rules you set on the Invoice ID, but you could consider to have an internal Invoice Id which could be the sequential 32-bits integer and an external Invoice ID that you can share with your customers.

This way your internal Id can start at 1 and you can add one to it everytime and the customer invoice id could be what ever you want.

Comment: @Macro yes it can be and thanks for creative idea, but my common sense says that this is not a good practice to do some "encryption" for your invoice ids, at least if it is possible to find a solution to produce authentic ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think Na Na has the correct idea with choosing a big number and counting down.  Start off with a large value seed and either count up or down, but don't start with the last placeholder. If you use one of the other placeholders it will give an illusion of a higher invoice count....if they are actually looking at that anyway.

The only caveat here would be to modify the last X digits of the number periodically to maintain the appearance of a change.

Answer (score 0):

Why not taking an easy readable Number constructed like

- first 12 digits is the datetime in a yyyymmddhhmm format (that ensures the order of your invoice IDs)
- last x-digits is the order number (in this example 8 digits)

The number you get then is something like 20130814140300000008

Then do some simple calculations with it like the first 12 digits

```
(201308141403) * 3 = 603924424209
```

The second part (original: 00000008) can be obfuscated like this:

```
(10001234 - 00000008 * 256) * (minutes + 2) = 49995930
```

It is easy to translate it back into an easy readable number but unless you don't know how the customer has no clue at all.

Alltogether this number would look like **603924424209-49995930** 
for an invoice at the 14th August 2013 at 14:03 with the internal invoice number 00000008.

Answer (score 0):

You can **write your own function** that when applied to the previous number generates the next *sequential random number* which is greater than the previous one but random. Though the numbers that can be generated will be from a finite set (for example, integers between 1 and 2 power 31) and may eventually repeat itself though highly unlikely. To *Add more complexity* to the generated numbers **you can add some AlphaNumeric Characters** at the end. You can read about this here [Sequential Random Numbers](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/node117.html).

An example generator can be

```
private static string GetNextnumber(int currentNumber)
{
      Int32 nextnumber = currentNumber + (currentNumber % 3) + 5;
      Random _random = new Random();
      //you can skip the below 2 lines if you don't want alpha numeric
      int num = _random.Next(0, 26); // Zero to 25
      char let = (char)('a' + num);
      return nextnumber + let.ToString();
}
```

and you can call like

```
string nextnumber = GetNextnumber(yourpreviouslyGeneratedNumber);
```